# Extra table in database Entity Framework Code First With Database Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it okay to have a table in the database that is not one of the entities when using code first with database migrations? Or will this interfere with the migrations? I want to put in a table to track some miscellaneous information.

Comment: It is ok, should just work with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this with no issues.  We do add the table through the migration though so we we can ensure all developers have the same schema.  If you want to skip this and go via SQL Management studio then you should have no issued either.

```
Sql(@"CREATE TABLE.....")
```

Comment: Cool.  How do you add a table via migration without adding a class for that table to the Dbcontext file ?

Comment: So add a migration file "add-migration MyMigration" from the package manager console.  This gives you the migration file.  The just add the line Sql(@"CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER....."); in the "UP" method.  Do the reverse in the "DOWN", i.e. Sql(@"DELETE TABLE CUSTOMER....");  More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx